# MapStruct Junit - Injecting Inner Mapper with CDI

Tags: java, mapstruct

Currently have Mapper containing inner Mappers (sometimes, themselves containing other inner Mappers).

They're defined like so:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi", uses = B.class)
public interface A {
    ADto toDto(AEntity entity);
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public interface B {
    BDto toDto(BEntity entity);
}
```

When the application runs, I can simply inject the main Mapper A without any problems and the entities get converted.

However, through JUnit, I can't seem to figure out how to instanciate inner mapper.

```
public class InformationChassisMapperTest {
    @InjectMocks
    public A mapper = new AImpl();

    public AEntity;
    @Before
    public void init() {
       AEntity = new AEntity();
       // fill entity...
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
       ADto = mapper.toDto(AEntity);
       // asserts...
    }
}
```

And I get an NPE because the inner mapper B is not instanciated during the mapping. Since the generated A mapper class uses @Inject B, during my JUnit tests CDI bean mapping is off (no arquillian). How could I mock or inject or instanciate the 2nd mapper in order to make my test pass?

I've looked other answers but they only cover Spring.

Answer (score 3):

Without creating a CDI context one option is to define the inner class using Mockito for example:

```
@Spy
private B uses = Mappers.getMapper(B.class);

@InjectMocks
private A mapper = Mappers.getMapper(A.class);

@Test
public void test() {
   ADto = mapper.toDto(AEntity);
   // asserts...
}
```

This will set the inner mapper for A when it uses B.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not mocking out Mapper and setup a test with CDI that can actually create all Mappers properly (not experienced with CDI to suggest a solution).

Having said that you can use the `Mapper#injectionStrategy` from 1.3. You can use a constructor injection and inject your mocks in it.